# Create a jar file using jdev that includes weblogic.jar

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, jar, jdeveloper

I've been having troubles lately in creating a jar file that can call a secured web service on Weblogic server using Jdev.

I've created a web service proxy which is handling the situation perfectly. My goal is to deploy this web service as a jar file so that I can use it in my other projects as a simple library.

I was able to deploy the project as a jar file, which in turn allowed me to use it's different methods to connect to the web service.
However, when I run the web service client on eclipse I get an error:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: weblogic/xml/crypto/wss/provider/CredentialProvider
    at WebServiceCaller.callGetCardDetailJar(WebServiceCaller.java:55)
    at WebServiceCaller.main(WebServiceCaller.java:29)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: weblogic.xml.crypto.wss.provider.CredentialProvider
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 2 more
```

The problem may be fixed by finding the weblogic.jar file and including it in the eclipse build path, but is there a way to deploy a jar file with all the library dependencies included in it ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to create a wlfullclient.jar (see oracle doc http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs103/client/jarbuilder.html ), but your class is not in it, it's rather in oracle.webservices.standalone.client.jar or in wls-api.jar or in weblogic.jar...  it's rather confusing, I think Oracle never managed to simplify this jar dependency problem, actually in earlier versions of WebLogic things were a lot simpler!